# Tools for developing Meteor

Tags: meteor

I've been watching the screencasts on the site and wondering what editor is being used? It looks like vi or vim (which one is it)? And at the bottom of the terminal says "JavaScript-IDE"? (is this a plugin for vi or vim) Thanks!

Comment: GNU Emacs.  In particular, http://emacsformacosx.com/

Comment: Just use whatever makes you comfortable. Some people say that WebStorm is not recommends but Atom.io is. Well, good luck running an IDE based on WebKit on a laptop with 3 years. Oh btw, Try to use Jlint with it and explain how it is a lot slower than WebStorm. It really depends on what do you want/expect from an IDE. The rest is just opinions. I know programmers who use VIM for everything and they're fine with it, I personally don't use it for everything but I'm not going to tell "Don't use it!", "Oh it's not recommended", etc.

Comment: ATOM. Some special packages are available for Meteor like autocomplete, snippet, api etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're using [Emacs](http://emacsformacosx.com/), but you can use whatever editor/IDE you want. My personal preference is [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2).

As far as I know, there aren't any editors that help you write Meteor code. Meteor is all Javascript, so the only thing an IDE could do is provide auto completion to the `Meteor` namespace and show you some docs. I think the general consensus is that an IDE like that wouldn't be too helpful at this point, since the docs change so frequently while Meteor is in very early stage development.

Happy Meteoring!

Comment: Thanks! I think they also may be using [js2-mode](https://code.google.com/p/js2-mode/) for emacs

Comment: I will try http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/ right now. They say it is very good for JS.

Comment: Actually the *only* editor that implements debugging and Meteor-specific features is [WebStorm](http://meteorpedia.com/read/Webstorm).

Answer (score 8):

## WebStorm

Webstorm 9 has [excellent Meteor support](http://meteorpedia.com/read/Webstorm).

---

## For Vim/Emacs

Another option would be to use TernJS and VIM/Emacs as explained by Slava Kim at Dev Shop.

**A Good Write up about it [here](http://devblog.me/meteor-plus-text-editor.html)**

Answer (score 8):

From Abigail Watson, Meteor expert:

***WebStorm is no longer the Meteor-Cookbook recommended Editor or Development Environment***.
We now recommend Atom.io since it's a pure-javascript editor, meaning we can extend the Meteor Isomorphic API to the Editor.

(https://github.com/awatson1978/meteor-cookbook/blob/master/cookbook/webstorm.md)

*Our **Meteor API for the Atom Editor** brings Isomorphic Meetor javascript to the editor with autocomplete, code snippets, color-coded grammar, syntax highlighting, and more! Code faster and with fewer mistakes!*

(https://github.com/awatson1978/meteor-api)

Comment: Does Atom support server-side debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Atom.io.  Growing well with community support.  Have been using it few days and cannot think of anything missed for my use.  The extension package system is pretty neat and available packages is growing quickly.

Comment: Atom doesn't support server debugging. While generally there's a religious war about editors and IDEs, the situation for Meteor is pretty clear: [WebStorm](http://meteorpedia.com/read/Webstorm) is miles ahead of any other IDE when it comes to Meteor support.

Answer (score 0):

Codelobster has special plug-in for MeteorJS: http://www.codelobster.com/meteorjs.html